# storing fetched data into a state component

Tags: firebase-storage

the submit function has another function named handleImageAdd() which will push the image collected from the form to the firebase storage.

```
const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
        setSubmitLoading(true)
        e.preventDefault()

        console.log("submitting form...") 

        await handleImageAdd()

        console.log("form submitted!")
        setSubmitLoading(false)
    }
```

this is the handleImageAdd() function,
when the image gets pushed to the storage, i am fetching its download url and storing it into a react state.
but the url don't get stored into the state on first call, it starts storing the url on second call. why is this happening?

```
const handleImageAdd = async(e) => {     
        console.log("adding image...") 
        const storageRef = storage.ref('images')
        const fileRef = storageRef.child(image.name)
        await fileRef.put(image)
        const url = await fileRef.getDownloadURL()
        console.log(url)
        setImageUrl(url)
        console.log("imageurl - ",imageUrl)
        console.log("image added!")
    }
```